# Unstoppable Process - Windows 10

Tags: windows, services, task-manager

There is an "Unstoppable" process that I cannot stop.  When I try to end the task in task manager, all of my programs immediately stop responding, including task manager itself, and my taskbar disappears.

Here is a picture of the service:[image]

I believe this service is from the ***ESET NOD32 antivirus*** I had uninstalled a while ago. I also cannot delete the **ESET** folder from the  **`C:\Program Files`** folder because this service is running.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous I ran as administrator but the stop option is greyed out. The software is already uninstalled

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous Yes

Comment: Have you booted in safe mode and see if it's running from there or if the Services.msc will allow you to set to disable? There's also an [SC](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) comment line tool for manipulating Window Services.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous I managed to set it to disable but it is still running, I will reboot now and report back.

Comment: Try this: http://support.eset.com/kb2289/?locale=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look in `services.msc` from `Run`

   [image]
2. Look thru the list and find the correlated service and select the <kbd>`Stop`</kbd> option from there. You can additionally <kbd>`Disable`</kbd> the service from starting by selecting the <kbd>`Properties`</kbd> option.

   [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [sc.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)
- [taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)